# Jenkins Pipleline using Groovy_Terraform plan job

Tags: sh, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-groovy

I am creating a pipeline using jenkins, trying to add a logic where if the terraform-plan is successful then only it will proceed with apply, therefore need get the return value as 0/1/2 from the sh terraform plan command but getting an error as below:

```
+ gt
+ echo 2
2
C:/Users/Smi/.jenkins/workspace/Pipe_Groovy@tmp/durable-33bd46fb/script.sh: line 2: gt: command not found
+ status
C:/Users/Smi/.jenkins/workspace/Pipe_Groovy@tmp/durable-33bd46fb/script.sh: line 2: status: command not found
[Pipeline] }
```

Below is the code:

```
sh "terraform init"
sh "terraform get"
sh "set +e; terraform plan -out=plan.out -detailed-exitcode; echo \$? &gt; status"
def exitCode = readFile('status').trim()
def apply = false
echo "Terraform Plan Exit Code: ${exitCode}"
if (exitCode == "0") {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
}
if (exitCode == "1") {
    slackSend channel: '#ci', color: '#0080ff', message: "Plan Failed: ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ()"
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}
if (exitCode == "2") {
    stash name: "plan", includes: "plan.out"
    slackSend channel: '#ci', color: 'good', message: "Plan Awaiting Approval: ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ()"
    try {
        input message: 'Apply Plan?', ok: 'Apply'
        apply = true
    } catch (err) {
        slackSend channel: '#ci', color: 'warning', message: "Plan Discarded: ${env.JOB_NAME} - ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ()"
        apply = false
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
    }
}
```

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Shell is trying to find a command named `gt` and fails, so your job fails at this step. You probably wanted to use `>` instead.

There is a way to get the exit code of a bash command without redirecting it into a file and than reading it:

```
def status = sh(returnStatus: true, script: "set +e; terraform plan -out=plan.out -detailed-exitcode")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

set +e
/terraform plan -var-file="${env}-custom.tfvars" -refresh=false -detailed-exitcode
PLAN_ECODE=$?
echo ${PLAN_ECODE}
set -e

if [ "${PLAN_ECODE}" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "ERROR!!! something is wrong planning!"
    exit 1
elif [ "${PLAN_ECODE}" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No changes!"
elif [ "${PLAN_ECODE}" -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "Applying in progress!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
    /terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file="${env}-custom.tfvars"
    echo "$i has been updated (check logs above for details)" >> /tmp/logs.txt
fi
```